# What is the file extension naming convention for c++20 modules?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have seen `.ixx`, `.cxx`, `.cpp` and `.cppm` used with c++20 modules.

- What are the different file extension naming conventions for c++20 modules?
- For which kind of unit (interface or implementation) is which extension usually used?

Comment: Remember that conventions like these are just conventions. Files can usually be named whatever you want and tools can be told to just use files with arbitrary names. File extensions are just names, they are usually not actually important. A C++ source file can be named "foo.doc" and you can compile it just fine - the compiler only cares about what a file *contains*, not what the file is named.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to give a more detailed answer, because it may be a good idea to try to avoid future inconsistencies in projects owing to early misunderstandings of a newborn feature.

The fact that GCC uses the name `cxx-modules` to designate its C++20 module management makes some people think the `.cxx` extension is the GCC counterpart of Microsoft `.ixx`. I see a potential future mess with that because when everybody understands what are interface and implementation module units, some developers would feel natural something like choosing `.ixx` for interfaces, `.cxx` for implementations, and `.cpp` for other files that may use modules but are neither interfaces nor implementations (like `main.cpp`). On the other hand, some other developers have already shown their intention to use `.cxx` for interfaces and something different (more usual) for implementations or non-module files. This will bring us to situations where different projects give a contradictory meaning of the `.cxx` extension (interface-specific vs implementation-specific).

Of course, everybody uses the extension (s)he wants for anything, but let's describe at least the complete philosophy of each compiler/development kit in order to give a hint about consistent naming patterns.

1. Microsoft reserves the `.ixx` extension for interface module units in its development tools, and uses `.cpp` for implementation units in its documentation (but I don't know if it would also accept `.cc` or `.cxx` instead of `.cpp`). The compiler also provides the `/interface` argument to allow declaring a module interface file having any arbitrary extension.
2. In CLANG, there are four possible extensions for interface module units, which are: `.cppm`, `.cxxm`, `.c++m` and `.ccm`. They are the respective counterparts for `.cpp`, `.cxx`, `.c++` and `.cc` that you should use for implementation module units and non-module units. (Think about it before rushing on `.ccm` claiming "oh that little cute three-letter extension is perfect for my modules!" )
3. In GCC there is no special extension for interface module units, so the proper way to distinguish interfaces and implementations is to use the same file extension but to apply a different suffix (for example : `gear_interface.cc` and `gear_implementation.cc`). Or alternatively, you may use a new extension specific for interfaces thanks to the `-x c++` argument, like `.ixx`, `.ccm`, or either the famous `.mpp` that seems to be more and more in use, despite not officially recognized in any worldwide tool (yet). But please, try not to reserve a historical C++ extension for this purpose; in ten years you would be happy not to have to switch between projects having contradictory file namings. (I distinguish "different" and "contradictory")

Now better informed, feel free to choose/craft your favourite solution.

Comment: I'm adding a tiny almost-opinional and almost-offtopic but properly related fact : You'll absolutely want to distinguish module interfaces from all the rest (including implementation modules), and this will be for the same reason you want the header files to have the extension `.h`... Because it allows you to know easily in which files you may find where shared functions and classes are defined. In beardy unices terms, you'll want to `grep -r $expr --include '*.ixx'` or `grep -r $expr --include '*.*m'` like you currently `grep -r $expr --include '*.h*'`.

Comment: For Microsoft, ".ixx" is the default but any file can be treated like a module interface regardless of extension (via the "/interface" command line option though most will set this in Visual Studio itself - see following link). See this here at this writing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/interface?view=msvc-170. Also see the "/internalPartition" command line option if the file is a module partition implementation file (here at this writing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/internal-partition?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Thanks Larry, I added this information in my answer. (The "/internalPartition" switch seems to be more related to defining which kind of partition a file contains than concerning the file extension management, so I only talked about "/interface")

Answer (score 3):

Conventions like these are part of build tools, and every compiler/build system with module support can simply be told which files contain what things.

In order to make building with modules more reasonable, the build system needs to be able to quickly identify which of the available files contributes to a module interface and which do not. That's what these extensions facilitate. Both ".ixx" and ".cppm" mean the same thing: the file is a module interface unit of some kind. ".ixx" is the default convention for Visual Studio.

Build tools don't really need to care about module implementation units (even importable implementation partitions don't really matter for the difficult parts of module builds), so no build tools have any expectations about extensions to identify such files.

Comment: So for every module interface (".ixx" or ".cppm") file I need an implementation file (usually ".cpp") (with the exception of a full abstract class)? 
I assume I would define a fully abstract class in a module interface file, correct?

Comment: @Kischy: I didn't say anything of the sort. Whether you use module implementation units or not is your choice. It's up to you and your needs. You asked about what file extensions mean, not how modules as a whole work.

Comment: Ok, I see, that is why I asked "and when should they be used? I change the question so it is more percise

Comment: @Kischy I have not heard about any efforts for standardization. If you are using Visual Studio, then you have encountered _attempts_ at guidelines for file extension names - but these are defined by Microsoft alone. As long as the compiler knows that the source file contains C++ code you can call the files whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

The `.ixx`, `.cppm`, and `.cxx` are module definition files in MSCV, Clang, and GCC respectively. The file contains the module code.

Once you have this file, you import them just as you would include a header file.

```
import name_of_module;
```

When compiling your `.cpp` file, you may include the deprecated `-fmodules-ts` option or `-std=c++20` if your compiler is new enough to use the official way.

You can read a good [general overview of modules here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170).

Comment: I think Microsoft decided on some standard naming convention. At least for GCC and Clang, file extension doesn't seem to matter as long as it recognizes a valid C++ file extension. I have largely used `.cpp` in all my test files: https://github.com/alexpanter/modules_testing.
Furthermore, I also think introducing more file extensions just introduces more complexity and confusion. I would definitely aim to argue that we should _only_ use `.cpp`.

Comment: I have a doubt about ".cxx" as being the preferred extension for GCC. The only example I find on GNU site uses ".cc": https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules

Comment: @Morgana https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html
GCC recognizes the following extensions as C++ files: cc, cp, cxx, cpp, CPP, c++, and C.

Comment: Oh, well, I meant I doubted ".cxx" was the preferred extension for C++20 modules in GCC. ;)