Do module files in C++ have to have a specific extension in their name?
I use CMake to build my C++ projects. If in my CMake file in my source files I add a file that ends in .cppm then MSVC knows to treat it as a module and everything works. I think there are some other extensions that it does this for. However I want my projects to build also on Clang and GCC, so as a standard way to do this using newer versions of CMake I do:
target_sources(myapp  
PUBLIC FILE_SET CXX_MODULES 
FILES

${PRJT_ROOT}/Engine/DiskStorage/DiskStorageManager.mymodule

)

This is supposed to be the way you do in in CMake. With the extension of .mymodule it doesn't work, I get the error:
Target "myapp" has source file

    C:/DiskStorage/DiskStorageManager.mymodule

  in a "FILE_SET TYPE CXX_MODULES" but it is not scheduled for compilation.

I don't know what this means and can't find anything in a search. If I give it the name extension .cppm it works, but I'm not sure if this is happening simply because Visual Studio recognises it as such. Basically the CMake method is failing.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75733706/what-is-the-file-extension-naming-convention-for-c20-modules.

I'm not sure if it's the case that it's insisting I name it .cpp, that wouldn't make sense, I've specifically told it it should be a module I should be able to name it .unicornsandrainbows

Not a demand by std. But MSVC unfortunately expects sth like .ixx. Since C++20 modules have not become popular, not many devs know and care. But this none-std restriction hinders the use of such a useful feature. I suggest all module users file a defect, so they probably consider a change of course in that regard.
